# Why do some websites have ?utf8=✓ in their title?

Tags: url, unicode, utf-8, hyperlink

I've noticed that a lot of websites, when searching or just browsing, will add a get variable called `utf` and set it equal to a check mark (`?utf8=✓`).

Two examples are:

- Dotabuff has its search URL include it. Example: dotabuff.com/search?utf8=✓&q=PPD
- Bibme also has its search URL include it. Example: bibme.org/mla/website-citation/search?utf8=✓&q=someurl.com

Answer (score 91, accepted):

URIs contain `utf8=✓` to force the client to send UTF-8.
It works because the key-value-pair (which is ignored by the target) contains a unicode-only character.

From [Is the use of “utf8=✓” preferable to “utf8=true”?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/168751):

> By default, older versions of IE (<=8) will submit form data in Latin-1 encoding if possible. By including a character that can't be expressed in Latin-1, IE is forced to use UTF-8 encoding for its form submissions, which simplifies various backend processes, for example database persistence.
>
> If the parameter was instead `utf8=true` then this wouldn't trigger the UTF-8 encoding in these browsers.

Comment: Is there a reason IE would use Latin other than being IE?

Comment: No, there's no reason for a long time now.

Comment: In fairness, depending on how the server was set up there's no guarantee that `utf8=✓` would actually be _ignored_ by the server, as the server has access to the entire URL.  Though if it's a site that's using it, it _probably_ isn't being used for anything by the server.

Comment: @Frank for whatever reason all/most IE products (Outlook/OWA for example) default to Latin-1 encoding out of the box unless configured otherwise. I assume interoperability(?) is one of the possible reasons.

Comment: GitLab does the same thing. I was like "How is this allowed, with all the URl encoding we usually need to do to escape special characters in the complete URL?"  Perfect answer.

Comment: @Jon has there ever been any web tech discussion involving IE not lamenting how bad IE is ? (actually anything microsoft. msvc compiles c++ badly, windows is slow, bloated and in a state of sociotechnical lock...)

Comment: @Jon it's very alright. I used it. It's thanks to Mark Russinovich and the new CEO, they proved they can do decent stuff. github is heading in a reasonable direction too