# Response Encoding

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am getting a response whose headers are :

> Content-Length:18588
>
> Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
>
> Date:Wed, 02 Dec 2015 12:58:51 GMT
>
> Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1

Is there a possibility that I change "application/json" encoded string to "text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1" encoding before sending it to the view? I am using Spring MVC.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ISO in 2015? Why not use UTF-8?

Comment: No, I want the controller to return it in application/json, but before sending it to the view, I want the manually change the response's content type to "text/plain". Response from api is application/json, which is correct, but I need to change the response to text/plain manually, due to some requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is to set the desired content type before sending response back to the client, so use `httpServletResponse.setContentType("text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1");`

This is method from [javax.servlet.ServletResponse(setContentType(java.lang.String type)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29)

Below excerpt from doc.

> **Sets the content type of the response being sent to the client, if the
>   response has not been committed yet. The given content type may
>   include a character encoding specification, for example,
>   text/html;charset=UTF-8.** The response's character encoding is only set
>   from the given content type if this method is called before getWriter
>   is called.
>
> This method may be called repeatedly to change content type and
>   character encoding. This method has no effect if called after the
>   response has been committed. It does not set the response's character
>   encoding if it is called after getWriter has been called or after the
>   response has been committed.
>
> Containers must communicate the content type and the character
>   encoding used for the servlet response's writer to the client if the
>   protocol provides a way for doing so. In the case of HTTP, the
>   Content-Type header is used.

**Please note:** You should use this method before you commit the response back to the client. See this from above excerpt - "*This method has no effect if called after the response has been committed. It does not set the response's character encoding if it is called after getWriter has been called or after the response has been committed.*"

---

On a side note:

- To make your applicable more scalable i.e. possibility to support more languages in future, use encoding scheme as "UTF-8".
- Do read my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33941751/html-form-does-not-send-utf-8-format-inputs/33987981#33987981) to get in-depth details on WHY?