# How to use tick ✓ in URL for boolean GET parameter

Tags: angularjs, utf-8, get, angular-ui-router

Being ispired by the [`utf8=✓` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338154/why-do-some-websites-have-utf8-in-their-title), I wanted to represent boolean values in my URLs with `✓` and `✖`.

So I wrote a simple [custom type](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:Type) for angular ui-router:

```
$urlMatcherFactory.type("boolTick", {
  encode: function(value) { return value ? '✓' : '✖'; },
  decode: function(value) { return value == '✓'; }
});
```

It works, indeed, but these sweet characters are encoded in the URL (i.e. `%E2%9C%93` and `%E2%9C%96` for `✓` and `✖`, respectively).

I wonder if there is any way to tell the browser (or ui-router) not to encode these characters?

See this plunker: [editor](http://plnkr.co/edit/KabB3OhUNPxFRe0tHGfZ) and [full screen view](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/KabB3OhUNPxFRe0tHGfZ/#/route1).

Comment: After looking at the [ui-router source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/a7d25c6/src/urlMatcherFactory.js#L322) seems that there's now way.

Comment: Thank you @miensol for finding it. I have reported [an issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2452) there.

Comment: [URIs only allow a subset of ASCII characters](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-1.2.1), so before transmitting an HTTP request, your browser *must* encode non-ASCII characters using percent encoding. Modern browsers choose to unescape UTF-8 characters in URLs for display, but that doesn't mean that raw UTF-8 is allowed in URLs.